# How can I fix `\amssymb` in {wsu} in overleaf

Tags: amssymb, overleaf

I am typing my summer report in overleaf and overleaf gives us to select from various kinds of projects (as an already made up format) and I selected Wright State Univ Thesis report format. Now in its preamble it is showing package `\amssymb` but when I type `\rtimes` it shows undefined control sequence. How can I fix this?

Here I am attaching the pic which shows the preamble-
[image]

Plese tell me how can I use `\amssymb` as typing so many math symbols is  getting impossible without it, now. I am 30% complete, so cannot rewrite it.

**P.S.-** I do note have any experience with latex and I am new to it.

Comment: all the `\usepackage` lines in the preamble are commented out -- preceded by a `%` sign.  remove the `%` sign and try again.  a commented-out package won't be loaded; the commenting is probably done here so that these packages are only suggestions; not all users may need all these packages, but the ones listed in comments are probably known to work, so a user starting a new project doesn't have to go exploring.

Comment: That template makes some really bad, out-dated suggestions: be careful what you uncomment!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

all the `\usepackage` lines in the preamble are commented out --
preceded by a `%` sign. remove the `%` sign and try again.

a commented-out package won't be loaded.

the commenting is probably done here so that these packages are only suggestions; not all users may need all these packages, but the ones
listed in comments are probably known to work, so a user starting a
new project doesn't have to go exploring.